# I can't get Requirejs to work with IE8 : 'appendChild(...)' is null or not an object in jQuery

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I've been strugling with requirejs for several hours now. I'm quite unfamiliar with javascript so the issue might be pretty basic. This in my config file.

```
requirejs.config({
    'baseUrl': '/js/lib',
    'paths': {
        'app': '../app',
        'jquery': 'jquery-1.10.1'
    }
});

define(function(require) {
    require('jquery');
});
```

It loads fine in chrome, however in IE8 I get the following error:

```
'appendChild(...)' is null or not an object  jquery-1.10.1.js, line 3506 character 3
```

I tried using the regular syntax, and various way to write the path. I found multiple ways to have it working in chrome, none of which worked in IE8!

Comment: Is your `doctype` set?

Comment: Use this
//remove require from the arguments

define(function() {
    require('jquery');
});

Comment: I have the doctype set correctly, and removing "require" from the arguments ends up not loading jquery. I've realized that the deprecated require-jquery.js works fine though.